# Javascript: Filtering twodimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, filter

There's plenty examples available on how to sort an javascript array based on it's numeric  values. What would however be appropriate way to fetch all elements from `myArray` with the property `prop1` with it's according value `value1`?

Here's my array:

```
var myArray = [
{
    "id":"2",
    "name":"My name",
    "properties":{"prop1":"value1"}
}];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just access it by dot or bracket notation and push the matching members to your new/filtered array, for example:

```
var newArray = [];
for(var i=0, l = myArray.length; i<l; i++) {
  if(myArray[i].properties.prop1 == "value1") newArray.push(myArray[i]);
}
```

Your question is a bit ambiguous though, if you're trying to get the `{"prop1":"value1"}` object, not the parent, then just change `newArray.push(myArray[i])` to `newArray.push(myArray[i].properties)`.

Comment: Really clean solution. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi Nick - Please have a look here; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4433004/jquery-js-sorting-array-based-upon-another-array

Answer (score 1):

Provide a compare function to sort by arbitrary properties:

```
function compareMyObjects(a, b) {
  var valA = a.properties.prop1.value1;
  var valB = b.properties.prop1.value1;

  if(valA > valB) return 1;
  if(valA < valB) return -1;
  return 0;
}

myArray.sort(compareMyObjects);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: This *sorts* the array, not filters it, also `prop1` is a string, so you've gone one property too far in the sort :)

Answer (score 0):

Go through each element in your array. For each element, check each property to see if it matches the one you're looking for.

```
function filterArray(array, property, value) {
    var newArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (var j in array[i].properties) {
            if (j === property && array[i].properties.hasOwnProperty(j)) {
                if (array[i].properties[j] == value) {
                    newArray.push(array[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't check the value anywhere, it just pushes all new objects to a new array, multiple times too if there's more than 1 child property.

Comment: why loop through when you can just access the property directly? :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var newarray=myarray.filter(function(itm){
   return itm.properties.prop1==='value1';
});
```

Filter, like the array methods indexOf and map, may be worth providing for browsers that don't have it- this version is from Mozilla Developer Site-

```
if(!Array.prototype.filter){
    Array.prototype.filter= function(fun, scope){
        var L= this.length, A= [], i= 0, val;
        if(typeof fun== 'function'){
            while(i< L){
                if(i in this){
                    val= this[i];
                    if(fun.call(scope, val, i, this)){
                        A[A.length]= val;
                    }
                }
                ++i;
            }
        }
        return A;
    }
}
```